# knockout carrying the data to Multiple View

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

Below is my code which is knocokout js,i have ListviewModel which is related to two views 1st and second view as below,Both views using the class name **UserDetailsView**, i am binding two views 1st and second view as below,my problem is, i have  click event on the 1st view  "Userview" i need to get data of clicked event which is **$root.UserView**, when i click this it should get all related value and pass to second view so i can bind the data using **knockout js** ,i am getting the value but unable to bind the data when i clicked **$root.UserView** so i used jquery in second view for  binding, but Now requirement is changed i need make another click event in second view so i can carry data to  another view,before that i need to bind the second view with Knockout js how it can be done need help

```
 function ListviewModel()
{
var self = this;
self.Listarray = ko.observableArray();
self.getUserList = function () {  
    var ListModel = {
        userId: UserID
    }
    jQuery.support.cors = true;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: JSON.stringify(ListModel),
        url: serverUrl + 'xxx/xxx/xxx',
        success: function (data) {

            self.Listarray($.map(data, function (item) {
                return new Listdata(item);
            }));
        }
    });
};

  //Click Function for UserPersonalview
 self.UserView = function (Listarray) {
    $("#userId").text(Listarray.userIdId());
    $("#userName").text(Listarray.UserName())
    document.getElementById('userProfilePic').setAttribute('src', "data:" +   Listarray.ProfilePictype() + ";base64," + Listarray.ProfilePicBase64());
    window.location.href = "#UserPersonalview";
}
self.UserProfile = function () {
    console.log(self.Listarray());

  }
  }

  //Model
  function Listdata(data)
 {    
 var self = this;
self.userId = ko.observable(data.userId);
self.userName = ko.observable(data.userName);
self.userProfilePicBase64 = ko.observable(data.userProfilePicBase64);
self.userProfilePictype = ko.observable(data.userProfilePictype);
self.userProfilepic = ko.computed(function () {
    return "data:" + self.userProfilePictype() + ";base64," +    self.userProfilePicBase64();
      }); 
    }



      //1st View

 <div data-role="view" id="Userview" class="UserDetailsView" data-layout="default">

  <div data-role="content" style="background-color:#fff!important">    
 <div>

  <ul style="list-style: none;" data-role="listview" id="hierarchical-listview" data-bind="foreach:Listarray">

  <li style="background-color:#FFF" data-bind="click:$root.UserView">

  <div style="width:100%;">
  <div style="width:50%;float:left">
  <span data-bind="text:$data.userId" style="display:none"></span>
  <img data-bind="attr: { src:$data.userProfilepic }" onclick="Imagepopover()" />
  <label style="width: 25%!important;" class="firendslisttext" data-bind="text:$data.userName"></label>
   </div>

   <div style="width:50%;float:left;margin: 0px -20px;">    
   </div>
   </div>
   </li>
   </ul>
  </div>   
    </div>
    </div>

   //second View
  <div data-role="view" id="UserPersonalview"  >
   <header data-role="header">
   <div data-role="navbar" class="UserDetailsView">
   <div class="content-header ">
   <ul style="list-style: none;" >
    <li data-bind="click:$root.UserProfile">
     <div class="km-leftitem">
    </div>
     <div class="block2" >
       <div class="inner" style="float:left" >
       <span id="userId" style="display:none"></span>
        <img data-responsive="" width="40" height="40" id="userProfilePic" src="" style="border-radius: 50%;" />
        </div>
      <div class="inner" style="float:left;margin-left:15px">
       <label id="userName" style="width: 100%!important;"></label>
        </div>
       </div>
       <div class="km-rightitem">
       <a data-align="right"><img src="images/icon-add.png" style="height:50px" /></a>
         </div>
          </li>
          </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

       </header>

    <div data=role="content"><div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's simple. Just save clicked object to an observable variable and bind related views against it (e.g. https://jsfiddle.net/hrmf6tot/).

Comment: i need to write click function then i need to navigate to different view after that i need to bind the value **self.UserView**

Comment: It was just the example to illustrate the whole concept. You should be able to change **your** code slightly to implement it.

Comment: @thanks it solved my problem